# An exercise concerning conditional expectation

Tags: probability

> Suppose one day you wake up in an empty big room with $n$ doors. The
> door numbered $i$ where $(1 \leq i \leq n)$ transport you to your room
> in an hour. All other doors will take the amount of the room number of
> hours to transport you to the same room, like a loop. For example, if
> you choose to open door $3$, in three hours you will appear in the
> same big room. Assume that you equally likely to choose any door. What
> is the expectation of the number of hours to get to your room?

### Try

Let $X$ be the number of hours until I arrive at my room. Since this problem is on conditional expectation chapter, I will condition on the number door:

$$ E(X) = E(X \mid D_1) P(D_1) + ... + E(X \mid D_i ) P(D_i) + ... + E (X \mid D_n ) P(D_n) $$

$$ = \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum_{k=1 k \neq i}^n E(X \mid D_k) + E(X \mid D_i) \right) $$

$$ = \frac{1}{n} \left( (n-1)E(X) + 1+2+...+n - i + 1 \right) $$

here is where I get stuck. Im assuming that the i is fixed. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. Just requires some simplification, noting that $1+2+\ldots+n = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ and starting from where you left off
\begin{align}
E(X) &= \frac{n-1}{n}E(X) + \frac{1}{2}(n+1) + \frac{1-i}{n} \\
\left(1-\frac{n-1}{n}\right)E(X) &= \frac{1}{2}(n+1) + \frac{1-i}{n} \\
E(X)&=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1) + 1- i.
\end{align}